# Do I understand this right? Comparing and assigning in one line of code?

Tags: c#

Can someone tell me if I understand this right.

```
  private void SetFontWeight(FontWeight weight)
        {
            boldButton.IsChecked = weight == FontWeights.Bold;
        }
```

Like what is getting me is how everything is in one line. Like they are comparing and then assigning.

So is there like some order. Logically it seems like it would be like

```
 boldButton.IsChecked = (weight == FontWeights.Bold);
```

Is that correct it first does comparison then assigns?

Or I guess the long way would be

```
if(weight == FontWeights.Bold)
{
     boldButton.IsChecked = true;
}
else
{
   boldButton.IsChecked = false;
}
```

I also find it kinda weird that they are comparing a struct(FontWeights) to a Class. I would have though it would be like

```
weight.IsBold == FontWeights.Bold
```

Comment: Like, she said, like, do you want to, like, go to the, like, movies?

Comment: I didn't think people would actually *write* like that too.

Comment: Hey, give chobo2 a break; at least there appears to be some semblance of spelling, punctuation and, like, sentence structure, dude!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup, [equality comparison has higher precedence than assignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28VS.71%29.aspx).  Assignment has basically the lowest precedence, so just about any other operators will be executed before assignment happens.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain that it's equivalent to

```
boldButton.IsChecked = (weight == FontWeights.Bold);
```

This sort of thing was inherited from C (originally) and it has to use parentheses to *force* assignment first:

```
if ((x = getcode()) == BAD_CODE) ...
```

In terms of your misgivings over the comparison, this is just one of the wonderful things that become possible when you're allowed to override comparison operators.

In fact, some would argue that this example makes *more* sense since you shouldn't have to worry about whether it's the `IsBold` property that you have to compare. The clas should (and does) figure that out because you're comparing it in a "boldness" sort of way :-)

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding is concerned, equality checks will be performed first. No matter you put brackets or not.

Sample code;

```
public boolean SampleFunction()
{
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
boolean c= false;
c= a==b;
return c;
}
```

This will first check if a is equal to b. So it will return boolean value and assign it to c.